# How to use a return value in another function?

Tags: python-2.7

say i have this code

```
def function(a):
    newInput = "hello, your input was " + a
    return newInput
```

now I am writing a code that wants to use that newInput from above is there a way to use that return value in another function?

example :

```
def function2(b):
    sentence = newInput + b
    return sentence
```

the inputs are strings if that makes any difference, thank you for the help

Comment: replace `sentence = newInput + b` with: `sentence = function(b)`

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
def function2(b):
    newInput = function(a)
    sentence = newInput + b
    return sentence
```

You have to specify `a` somewhere but assigning a function to a variable effectively assigns the return value to that variable.